# What is the role of Encryption Key in Coveo for sitecore

Tags: coveo

My understanding is Encryption key is used to read the passwords. Why is it stored in Data folder and Core DB (properties) table?

In my case say I am creating a new environment by copying the Website from environment A and DB from Environment B. What should I do to setup coveo in the new environment? Should I go with the Encryption Key in A (Data) or B (DB)?
or Disable all the Coveo config and install the Coveo for Sitecore Package newly ?

Please advice

Sitecore version 8.1
Coveo 4.0 On premise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encryption key used to encrypt the sensitive configuration nodes of Coveo. The encryption keys are stored in the core database with the latest versions. So that can be shared by the farm starting version [4.0.780](https://docs.coveo.com/en/3172/coveo-for-sitecore-v4/2016-coveo-for-sitecore-4-0-releases#release-notes-for-december-2016-40780). The file system based encryption key is legacy mode and can be turned on with a setting.

> The legacy file system based encryption key can be turned on

```
 <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Coveo.Encryption.UseEncryptionKeysFileStorage" value="true" />
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

To validate if the encryption key is in Core db. Please follow the steps mentioned in [article](https://answers.coveo.com/questions/12489/how-to-validate-the-encryption-key-has-switched-to.html).

I had similar thought during migration. I cleared all the coveo files and installed the Coveo package and ran the configuration wizard. It worked, So you can keep this as a backup option.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here is mostly correct but could lead you astray: since the May 2019 update of Coveo for Sitecore, the encryption keys are actually stored in the Web database and not the Core.

See the following:
https://docs.coveo.com/en/2264/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/deploy-coveo-for-sitecore-on-the-content-delivery-servers#step-2-ensuring-access-to-the-encryption-keys

https://connect.coveo.com/s/article/6049

Comment: Thanks Jamie for the answer